# How to convert DNAbin to DNAStringSet?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I am trying to get an alignment in ape  from R with this code:

```
library(muscle)
#https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/muscle.html 

muscle(x, exec = "muscle", MoreArgs = "", quiet = TRUE)
```

but the console says:

> ```
>  Error in muscle(x, exec = "muscle", MoreArgs = "",  : 
> input must be an object of class XStringSet: DNAStringSet, RNAStringSet, or AAStringSet
> ```

Comment: Please add the data you wish to coerce to DNAStringSet and what you've tried so far that doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean `DNAbin` from the `ape` package? In that case I believe you need to go the route `DNAbin` → `as.character` → `DNAStringSet`.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert any DNAbin to DNAStringSet by

```
library(magrittr)

yourDNAbin %>% as.character %>% lapply(.,paste0,collapse="") %>% unlist %>% DNAStringSet
```

if your DNAbin is: xxx DNA sequences in binary format stored in a list.
If it is stored in a matrix as.list it first.